# closure and for loops consuing me

Tags: javascript, closures

alright guys. every singe time i think i understand fundamental JS quirks i go insane and realize i don't at all... while the part of this that usually stumps people DOES NOT for me... i am so confused as to why this console.logs '10' ten times. WHY is it not '9' 9 times... the loop clearly says i < 10.... i don't understand why the loop runs an extra time to ten here...

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

to add to that why does this loop below respect the i<10 thing and produce 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.. clearly in the example below the loop respects the 'until i is less than 10 (which is 9) why does it not do that in the first example and run until i is 10?

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  console.log(i)
}
```

everytime i think i understand this stuff i don't its actually starting to drive me a bit insane. ive been coding over a year now and still am confused by this. i understand the call stack stuff and the closure to a degree. most people get stumped and say it will print 9 every second etc... i get that part. but why is it 10 and not 9?! also plz in layman's terms as best you can. i understand that the ++ part actually runs at the beginning of each iteration (except for the first) but i still am so confused as to why ANYTHING with closure or call stack etc would create an extra run of the loop.

also if you are REALLY up for it too... why THE F*** does this produce '1' and not '2' lol...... please answer the first question though. that is my primary confusion right now

```
for(let i=0; i<2; i++){
  setTimeout(()=>console.log(i))
  i++
}
```

Comment: Its because the for loop executes faster than the 1 second timeout and by that time the variable i has reached 10 and therefore all the scheduled timeouts will log 10.

Comment: but why does it even reach 10. its i<10 not i<=10... why is it 10 and not 9? why doesn't the loop stop at 9?

Comment: plz re read my question man. you're explaining the call stack and timeout. thats not the part that confuses me. why is it 10 and not 9

Comment: i has to equal 10 or the loop would never exit. Your timeout code executes after the loop has exited hence it logs 10.

Comment: @ptothep not quite, even if you would count up to a billion which would probably take longer than a second, it'll still log a billion as the timeout always executes after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

actually at last iteration the for loop increment `i` value to `10`. then the for loops evaluates the condition `i < 10`. since `i` is now `10` the block statement doesn't run again, but its current value is 10.

the reason the second one prints 1,2,3,4 and the first prints 10,10,10 is because the second one the code is sync, while the first one is async (setTimeout). setTimeout will be only be executed after the callstack empties. by that time `i` will be `10`. since `i` is defined as `var`, which is not blocked scoped like `let`, all console.log(i) prints `10`.

the second goes until the `9` because once it reaches the last iteraction `i` is `9` and prints `9`. Then `i` is updated to `10` and the next block doesn't run because now `i < 10` is no more valid. `i` is now `10` but there is no more console.log to be executed. if you console.log(i) after the for loop will print `10`.

Meanwhile the async code, each setTimeout can only execute `console.log` once the callstack from the event loop is clear. when the event loop is clear, the for loop already has finished its execution and `i` is now `10`. now each console.log will be executed and the value they find for `i` is `10`.

Comment: OK BUT why does it go to 9 and not 10 in the second one... i understand the synchronous stuff.... i understand the call stack etc... im asking WHY the first goes to 10 and the second goes to 9 lol... you guys are clearly not reading my entire post. i appreciate the help but plz read the post

Comment: I updated the post to make it more clear, but maybe for you to get a clearer view you should also search for texts about the `event loop` to understand its functionality better.

Comment: dude i just re read your comment after being updated. thank you so much. NOW I UNDERSTAND!

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is (more or less) the same to a while loop, and when looking at that we might find the answer:

```js
    let i = 0;
    while(i < 10) {
      console.log("inside loop", i); // 0,1,...,9
      i++;
    }
    // at this point, the loop exited with i = 10
    console.log("after loop", i);
```

On the last iteration, `i` is 9 when passing the body, then it gets incremented to 10, then `10 < 10` evaluates to false and the loop exits. Then somewhen the timeout calls back and 10 gets logged.

Comment: thank you. this helps.. somewhat. STILL confused why the first one goes up to 10 and the second one goes up to 9. I AM NOT CONCERNED about ANY of the caxll stack, execution, sync stuff. im literally asking WHY it goes to 10 in first on and only 9 in the second one. if a for loop is like a while looop then why do both perform didfferently here?

Comment: they don't, that's the point. You log *after the loop finished execution* and thus `i < 10` must be false, thus it has to be 10.

Comment: Also please take your time to read the answers, so did we with your question.

Comment: the simplest way to reframe my question is why does ```for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  console.log(i)
}
console.log(i)```   produce 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 AND THEN 10. i am so confused still about simple for loops

Comment: cause computers are built this way. They read from registers and write to registers and jump over instructions (and that's basically all they are capable of). The code writes 10 into some register (`i++`) then reads from the register, compares the value to 10, and if true jumps out of the loop. The register holds 10 afterwards.

Comment: im still utterly confused. really i am. i appreciate the help guys but this makes no sense to me still. if for(var i=0; i<10; i++) essentially means "run this until i is less than 10... or basically until i=9". why when i console log i OUTSIDE the loop it suddenly becomes 10? when did that happen? i thought the loop stopped at 9 because 9 is less than 10? lol... oh and why does it print "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" and then all of a sudden i becomes 10 outside the loop? i feel like im going a bit insane i've been trying to wrap my head around this for hours now

Comment: No, the loop stops if `i < 10` is *false*. `i` can't be 9.

Comment: so then why does i only reach 9 inside the loop? im confused if i can't be 9 then why is i literally 9 at the end of the loop? but then suddenly becomes ten outside the loop.

Comment: im starting to understand now a bit. your last comment got me halfway there.but still not fully grasping . this really is showing me how little i know about JS haha

Comment: `i = 9; console.log(i); i++; console.log(i);`

Comment: OK. so the loop stops because 10<10 is false. but i still ends up being 10 at the end of the loop. its jsut not logged because the loop stops. so i is 10 at the end of the loop BUT the 10 is not logged? im just so confused as to where and when the i goes from 9 to 10. does i end up being 10 at the end of the loop but it is not logged?

Comment: i = 9; console.log(i);  <===here the console logging of the loop stops BUT   i++; happens one more time. in the loop? 10 is not logged because 10<10 is false and the loop has stoped BUT the loop exits with i being equal to 10?... after the loop exits we are able to console.log(i) as 10 because the loop did exit with i being 10. is this correct? sorry for all this confusion... this topic is confusing to say the least!

Comment: with a debugger you can step through the snippet above step by step and verify that on your own ...

Comment: i think i finally understand. thanks for your time and patience